# What does this PHP foreach loop do? (Something to do with creating references to each element in an array?)

Tags: php, arrays, reference, foreach, ampersand

Recently, I was trying to create a copy of a PHP array, except that instead of the copy of the array containing values, I wanted the copy to contain references to values.
My main motivation for this was to use the `call_user_func_array` function in conjunction with the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` functions to create a wrapper function for handling prepared statements.

While trying to figure out how to do this, I came across the following code:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4); // The array to make a copy of with references
$ref_arr = array();       // The new array that will contain the references

foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) {
  $ref_arr[$key] = &$val;
}
```

The above code does in fact give me what I want by creating a second array that's identical to the first except that the elements in the array are references to values instead of values themselves, however, I don't understand how it works.

I understand what the ampersand (`&`) does in PHP, but I don't understand why both instances of `$val` in the foreach loop have to be referenced as `&$val`.

If anyone could please explain what exactly is happening in the foreach loop above, I would be very appreciative.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first instance has to be a reference. Otherwise you would only get a local copy. Consider this code:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4); 
foreach ($arr as $val)
    $val = 5;
print_r($arr);
```

This code would still print 1,2,3,4 as you are not altering the values in the array, but a copy.

The same logic applies for the second instance. Without &, it would only assign the current value of the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I commented in John's answer, it was both of your answers that made this click for me. My understanding now is as follows: The first `&$val` is necessary in order to reference the values stored in the original array `$arr`, as opposed to making a second copy of each value and storing that copy in the `$val` variable. After that, the second instance of `&$val` is required in order to assign a reference to the array element denoted by `$ref_arr[$key]`. In other words, without that second `&`, just a value (and not a reference) would be assigned to `$ref_arr`.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` requires values to be passed by reference. So all that function does is create an array that references values in the original array. That makes `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` happy. It's kinda silly but it's what we have to do to call `call_user_func_array()` with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Ref: see the manual for [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

> Care must be taken when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in conjunction with call_user_func_array(). Note that mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be passed by reference, whereas call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a list of variables that can represent references or values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Your statement about the function creating an array that references values in the original array is what made this click for me. Actually, it was a combination of that statement and Milan's answer. Without the two of you describing the situation two different ways, I would not have gotten this. With that said, Milan's answer honestly did help me a bit more, as such, I decided to give him credit for the right answer. (Really though, I wish I could have given you both credit for the right answer.)